# App structure for storing large quantity of records

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, core-data, data-structures

I am creating an iOS app that deals with real estate listings. The current structure is as follows:

1. Device contacts server and downloads an index file which contains all current record IDs on the server and the last time each record was modified.
2. Each core data record on the device is checked against the index file and either:
   a) the record is up to date and nothing happens.
   b) the record is out of date, is deleted from the device and reloaded from the server.
   c) the record is not part of the index file and is deleted from the device.
   d) no record is found on the device with the listing ID and is downloaded from the server.

I use an index file because I have to download only a small part of the data for each record in order to compare.

My problem is this, I currently have about 1250 test records on the server. With the current setup it is taking almost 3 minutes (using WiFi) to complete the initial index check routines. There has to be a better way to handle a large number of records in a iOS app. Am I wrong for trying to load all the records in core data up front?

For reference I am including the ListingRecord.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * amenitiesText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * bodyLabel1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * bodyLabel2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * bodyLabel3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * brokerID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * companyID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * descriptionText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * displayPrice;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * featuredListing;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * headerLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * headerPhoto;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastUpdate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitudeData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * listingID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * listingType1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * listingType2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * listingType3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * listingType4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * listingType5;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * listingType6;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * listingType7;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * listingType8;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitudeData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * numberPrice;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * photo1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * photo2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * photo3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * photo4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * photo5;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * pinLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * thumbnailPic;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * sessionID;
```

The index file contains the listingID and the lastUpdate and compares those against the core data records on the device.

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us how are you doing the initial index check routine.

Comment: what format is the listing file? e.g. XML? Have you thought of returning a JSON object to represent the index? it might speed things up.

Comment: @sosborn - I do a NSURLRequest to get the XML file and then do a NSXMLParser to get the data. Do you want more details?

Comment: @bennythemink - No all that familiar with JSON but would it not be about the same in size than XML and the comparing with core data records take about the same amount of time?

Comment: @sangony- Yeah, I was looking for how you do the comparisons. That is probably your biggest bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there are two bottle necks, the communication with the server and the check routine. To help solve the first bottle neck I highly recommend JSON, if used correctly it should reduce the size of the data to be passed from the server to the device and its very very easy to work with. It should also help with the second bottle neck, the check routine as you simply grab the returned data from the server, convert it to a JSON object representation with one line of code and then you are basically dealing with a NSDictionary of values.

Comment: Are you suggesting I go with JSON for only the index file or the whole package (so to speak) and drop the XMLParser completely? Do you think my approach of wanting to load everything up front is correct or should I take a load as the user selects approach?

Comment: It completely depends upon your situation and how much code you would have to re-engineer. If I was you I'd start by testing how long it takes to pass the index as JSON data from the server. If you think it is within an acceptable time frame then load all at once, other wise break it up into smaller chucks and load it as the user selects.

Comment: Also if the downloading of the rest of the package is quick then maybe just keep it as XML based and use JSON only for the index. Again it totally on how much re-engineering it will take. I prefer to have it all as JSON but if its a major job to convert and there is not a significant speed increase to the user then it may not be worth it.

Comment: Ok. This is more of learning project so I will go with all JSON and see what happens. One last point, currently I have it setup that every time a new index file is downloaded, a new 'session id' is part of that file. I then loop through all the core data files, do my checks, and write the new session id to each core data record. I do this so I know that any record without the session id was not part of the index file and has to be deleted. This strikes me as a little backwards but I could not come up with anything else. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing springs to mind I'm afraid sangony. Your logic is good, there may be a better solution but I cannot think of any at the moment sorry. Also The suggestion below by user523234 is a good one. If your UI does not entirely depend on the information from the server then processing in a separate thread while letting the user navigate the app is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do all this at once, I would arrange your flow logic so that you can do this "initial index check routines" in the background thread.

Another option would be sending the index file to the server and let your backend server do the work and it returns only the lists for adding, deleting, updating, etc.  This would depend on if your backend server is capable of doing this.

Comment: You make a very good point and something I have not considered. I am using a 4D server (4d.com) as my back-end database. Not sure if what you are suggesting can be done but it might be the only feasible way once listings reach the 10,000 plus mark.